# VBA applying border around cell that contains value/text

Tags: excel, vba

I was just wondering if anyone could help me adapt this code please?

```
Dim border As Range
Dim brng As Range

Set border = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each brng In border
If Not IsEmpty(brng) Then
brng.BorderAround _
        LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
        Weight:=xlThin
End If
Next brng
```

Please see the picture below for what I am trying to achieve.

The left screenshot is what I am currently getting but I would like the border to cover the blank cell as well.

[image]

Comment: You say _I would like the border to include the empty cell_ and yet your code includes `If Not IsEmpty(brng) Then`.  Do you see the connection?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I am just really new to this VBA stuff, thank you for spotting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

With rng.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

With rng.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

With rng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

With rng.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

With rng.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

With rng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

End Sub
```

A shorter version of code using numeric index of constants seen in the documentation about enumeration:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Byte

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'enumeration code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlbordersindex

For i = 7 To 12 Step 1
    With rng.Borders(i)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Although, the code is perfectly fine. I have came across another problem, where I am 2 table with blank row.

Comment: @TK4795 That's a different question. You should never replace your original question with a different one because now the answer does not make sense. Open a new question with this issue and leave the question as it was originally.

Answer (score 1):

You can test a logic like below which uses `CurrentRegion` property of `Range` to identify contiguous cell data.

```
Sub ApplyRegionBorders()
    Dim Rg As Range
    '\\ Loop through all cells
    For Each Rg In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Len(Rg.Value) > 0 Then
            '\\ Apply on each separate region
            With Rg.CurrentRegion.Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End If
    Next Rg
End Sub
```